# Android uber error No authentication challenges found

Tags: android, uber-api

I am trying to implement Uber in my Android application. I got error "No authentication challenges found" when authenticate a user.

I have created an app in Uber and given the following scope to the app as shown in the image.

[image]

and my Redirect URL  is : `http://localhost/auth`

In my Android app I have given following scope list for authorize call

```
public static final String SCOPES = "profile history_lite history";
```

and  added the params list to the api.

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("response_type", Constants.CODE));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", Constants
        .getUberClientId(this)));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", Constants.SCOPES));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", Constants
        .getUberRedirectUrl(this)));
```

please help me on this to how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate this Uber SDK for Android into your app Click [here](https://github.com/Neno0o/Uber-Android-SDK). Note that this still in beta-version.